# Solaris Express: is there a command line version of Package Manager?

Tags: solaris, packages, package-management

From documentation I can find (e.g. here http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19963-01/html/820-7799/new-user.html), package manager seems to be only available as a GUI tool (as opposed to a command line utility).

Is it possible for me to run the package manager in the same manner of `yum` or `apt-get`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly the link you've provided ([see here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19963-01/html/820-7799/new-user.html)) already talks about GUI and CLI (Command-Line Interface) and refers to pkg(1) man page. So I just recommend using `man pkg` to get information about the package manager command-line interface.

Unfortunately I am not using Solaris Express but rather "normal" Solaris at office. Here you install packages using `pkgadd`, remove them with `pgkrm` and get information about packages using `pkginfo`. If Solaris Express uses the same package manager then you can simply install packages using `pkgadd -d <Package-Name>`.

Comment: you're right about 'man pkg'! Thanks. Don't know why they call the CLI counterpart 'IPS framework'. Rather confusing...

Comment: CLI is a common abbreviation for "Command Line Interface" - so it's likely exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I know what CLI stands for. :-) I just did not know what IPS is referring to. Cheers

Comment: Just in case you still don't, it is Image Packaging System: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19963-01/html/820-6572/index.html